# Binary classification without positive samples

Tags: classification, one-class

I have been given a trainingset of negative samples, and am asked to use this to classify a testset.

I am aware of how classification can be done when you have some positive, and some negative samples, but have been unable to find an approach that covers the case where there are no positive samples at all!

I hope there is a good approach for this, so far I have come up with the following two options but am not really satisfied:

1. Guess which fraction of samples should be positive, use naive bayes to determine the quality of the match with my training set and set the treshold just high enough to let it result in the right percentage being classified as positive.
2. Try to create my own set of very probable positive results (perhaps by means of the following method with a strict treshold), and then use this set as if it were a set of positives to train any standard classification model.
3. Instead of classifying negative vs positive, I classify negative vs other. Anything that is very other will be considered positive, and the rest negative.

So to conclude:

#### Is there a good way to do classification when you only have negative samples, or if not, which mentioned approach seems to be most promising?

Comment: If you have only one class (= negative), you are forced to use one-class methods (e.g. [one-class SVM](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume2/manevitz01a/manevitz01a.pdf)). You can't treat negatives as if they are positive and expect to get a meaningful result (your first option). Creating fictional positives would be a good approach if that is possible.

Comment: @MarcClaesen Thanks, you lead me to the term I was looking for: [One-class classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-class_classification) and I even found [an example in R](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76365/examples-for-one-class-svm-in-r)